# Unable Setup Picker in Popover

Tags: ios

I am having a problem communicating with a picker inside a popover for the iPad.  I am using .xib files  to support iOS4.  The pickers for the iPhone all work perfectly.  I have spent a week searching the web for a solution

I have ViewController and PopoverViewController

In the ViewController a button calls the popover which displays the PopoverViewController picker, correctly.

The button includes the following code to show the appropriate row in the middle, I can see that the code is being read at run time, but nothing happens.  Is someone able to suggest to me where I have gone wrong?

```
PopoverViewController *po = [[PopoverViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@”PopoverViewController” bundle: nil];
[po.popoverPickerStop selectRow: 7 in Component: 0 animated:NO;
[po.popoverPickerStop selectRow: 1 in Component: 1 animated:NO;
[self btnShowPopover:btnStop];
```

Answer (score 0):

My top answer here may help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8896251/550177

Try creating a strong property for `PopoverViewController`.

Comment: I am reviewing that code, but essentially it does not seem to take me forward.  I had already a strong property for PopoverViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I can now answer my own question for anyone with the same problem.  You will find it resolved here:

[Select row After UIPickerView is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812995/select-row-after-uipickerview-is-loaded)

It is, as I suspected, a matter of getting the sequence of events right.  I just did not know how to do that!