# How to select UIPicker first row value xcode?

Tags: iphone, view, row, selection, uipickerview

This is my code but its not working properly

I want to select first row value when i press the done button

I tried this code, there are two views and and in each view there are two pickers,

if i select the **firstPickerView** value of first row then the **2nd picker** first value automatically changed,

I don't know what to do or how to solve this issue

Please Help Me i am new in this programing need your support

**Here is my code:**

```
- (IBAction)pickerViewDoneBtn:(id)sender {

    if (self.amountScratchView) {

        [self myViewDown:self.amountScratchView];

        [self.amountScratchView removeFromSuperview];
    }

   if (self.operatorScratchView) {

        [self myViewDown:self.operatorScratchView];

        [self.operatorScratchView removeFromSuperview];
    }

   if (self.topUpOperatorView) {

      [self.operatorLbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [operatorDataArray 

objectAtIndex:[self.topUpPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]]];

        [self myViewDown:self.topUpOperatorView];

        [self.topUpOperatorView removeFromSuperview];
    }
   if (self.topUpAmountView) {

        [self.amountLbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [amountDataArray 

objectAtIndex:[self.topUpAmountPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]]];


        [self myViewDown:self.topUpAmountView];

        [self.topUpAmountView removeFromSuperview];
    }

}
```

OR
please tell me how to select the first value in row in **upickerview**

Answer (score 1):

You can easily write following code to select first row in pickerView as give code below.

```
 [picker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

set this code in your done button action.Here picker is pickerView outlet

you can also use delegate method to select row as

```
picker.delegate=self;

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSLog(@"selected row is %i",row);
}
```

prefer this link [Select first row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/813029/1305001)

Comment: no, its not working :(

if (self.topUpOperatorView) {

[self.topUpPickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];

        [self myViewDown:self.topUpOperatorView];

        [self.topUpOperatorView removeFromSuperview];
    }

Comment: I am not able to understand your entire code please paste it in pastebin.com and give me the link

Comment: are you sure it is getting entered in self.topUpOperatorView condition.Try applying NSLog in this condition.

Comment: use this operatorScratchPicker instead of topUpPickerView to select row

Comment: where you have declared topUpAmountPickerView and is it added to pickerView UI